# How to make this simple C program start over?

Tags: c

First time poster here.  I am taking a C programming course in school right now, having only taken programming essentials in the past.  I have been struggling along but somehow managed to get through everything up to week 5.

Basically, here is what I have so far.  What I am trying to do is have this program recycle back to the menu selection screen after you have already ran through it once.  I believe I need to put everything in a while loop, but I have tried to add it in, but all that happens is I end up with the program asking me to input the hours for the choice I already selected.  I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2015 if that helps at all.

Thanks for any help/explanations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#define BASEPAY1 8.75
#define BASEPAY2 9.33
#define BASEPAY3 10
#define BASEPAY4 11.20
#define BASEHRS 40
#define OVERTIME 1.5
#define AMT1 300
#define AMT2 150
#define RATE1 0.15
#define RATE2 0.20
#define RATE3 0.25

int main(void)
{
   int hours;
   float gross;
   float net;
   float taxes;
   int choice;

   printf("\n\nMenu\n----------\n\n");
   printf("1) $8.75/hr\n");
   printf("2) $9.33/hr\n");
   printf("3) $10.00/hr\n");
   printf("4) $11.20/hr\n");
   printf("5) quit\n\n");

   printf("Enter the number that corresponds to your rate or press 5 to quit.\n");
   scanf_s("%d", &choice);

   switch (choice) {
      case 1:
             printf("Enter the number of hours worked this week: \n");
             scanf_s("%d", &hours);

             if (hours <= BASEHRS)
                gross = hours * BASEPAY1;
             else
                gross = BASEHRS * BASEPAY1 + (hours - BASEHRS) * BASEPAY1 * OVERTIME;
             if (gross <= AMT1)
                taxes = gross * RATE1;
             else if (gross <= AMT1 + AMT2)
                     taxes = AMT1 * RATE1 + (gross - AMT1) * RATE2;
                  else
                     taxes = AMT1 * RATE1 + AMT2 * RATE2 + (gross - AMT1 - AMT2) * RATE3;
             net = gross - taxes;

             printf("gross: $%.2f \n", gross);
             printf("taxes: $%.2f \n", taxes);
             printf("net: $%.2f \n", net);

             break;
      case 2:
           printf("Enter the number of hours worked this week: ");
           scanf_s("%d", &hours);

           if (hours <= BASEHRS)
              gross = hours * BASEPAY2;
           else
              gross = BASEHRS * BASEPAY2 + (hours - BASEHRS) * BASEPAY2 * OVERTIME;
           if (gross <= AMT1)
              taxes = gross * RATE1;
           else if (gross <= AMT1 + AMT2)
                   taxes = AMT1 * RATE1 + (gross - AMT1) * RATE2;
                else
                   taxes = AMT1 * RATE1 + AMT2 * RATE2 + (gross - AMT1 - AMT2) * RATE3;
           net = gross - taxes;

           printf("gross: $%.2f \n", gross);
           printf("taxes: $%.2f \n", taxes);
           printf("net: $%.2f \n", net);

           break;
    case 3:
           printf("Enter the number of hours worked this week: ");
           scanf_s("%d", &hours);

           if (hours <= BASEHRS)
              gross = hours * BASEPAY3;
           else
              gross = BASEHRS * BASEPAY3 + (hours - BASEHRS) * BASEPAY3 * OVERTIME;
           if (gross <= AMT1)
              taxes = gross * RATE1;
           else if (gross <= AMT1 + AMT2)
                   taxes = AMT1 * RATE1 + (gross - AMT1) * RATE2;
                else
                   taxes = AMT1 * RATE1 + AMT2 * RATE2 + (gross - AMT1 - AMT2) * RATE3;
           net = gross - taxes;

           printf("gross: $%.2f \n", gross);
           printf("taxes: $%.2f \n", taxes);
           printf("net: $%.2f \n", net);

           break;
    case 4:
           printf("Enter the number of hours worked this week: ");
           scanf_s("%d", &hours);

           if (hours <= BASEHRS)
              gross = hours * BASEPAY4;
           else
              gross = BASEHRS * BASEPAY4 + (hours - BASEHRS) * BASEPAY4 * OVERTIME;
           if (gross <= AMT1)
              taxes = gross * RATE1;
           else if (gross <= AMT1 + AMT2)
                   taxes = AMT1 * RATE1 + (gross - AMT1) * RATE2;
                else
                   taxes = AMT1 * RATE1 + AMT2 * RATE2 + (gross - AMT1 - AMT2) * RATE3;
           net = gross - taxes;

           printf("gross: $%.2f \n", gross);
           printf("taxes: $%.2f \n", taxes);
           printf("net: $%.2f \n", net);

           break;
     case 5:
           return 0;
     default:
           printf("Invalid choice, please enter the number that corresponds ");
           printf("to your rate or press 5 to quit.\n\n");
    }


  system("PAUSE");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show the code with your `while` loop attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the value of `choice` in every steps. So, I would code something like:

```
int main(void)
{
    // some code
    int choice;
    bool loop = true;

    while(loop)
    {
       printf("\n\nMenu\n----------\n\n");
       // print the menu

       printf("Enter the number that corresponds to your rate or press 5 to quit.\n");
       scanf_s("%d", &choice);

       switch (choice) {
       // cases 1-4
       case 5:
           loop = false;
           break;

       default:
           printf("Invalid choice.\n\n");
       } // exit from switch
    } // exit from while-loop

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the while loop is AFTER the prompt for wage rate. So it only executes that prompt once.

Simply move the line

```
while ( choice < 5) {
```

To before the line

```
printf("\n\nMenu\n----------\n\n");
```

Now it will loop the whole program as required.

Comment: What if user enter `0` ?

Comment: Then it will print `Invalid choice, please enter the number that corresponds to your rate or press 5 to quit.`

Comment: Also be sure to set choice to some value less than five before using it in the while loop. It's good practice to define variables before using them.

Comment: I had tried that, but it kept giving me errors about choice not be initialized.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>



#define BASEPAY1 8.75
#define BASEPAY2 9.33
#define BASEPAY3 10
#define BASEPAY4 11.20
#define BASEHRS 40
#define OVERTIME 1.5
#define AMT1 300
#define AMT2 150
#define RATE1 0.15
#define RATE2 0.20
#define RATE3 0.25

char *szMainMenu=
    "\n\nMENU:\n"
    "----------\n"
    "\n"
    "  1) $8.75/hr\n"
    "  2) $9.33/hr\n"
    "  3) $10.00/hr\n"
    "  4) $11.20/hr\n"
    "  5) quit\n"
    "\n"
    "Enter the number that corresponds to your rate or press 5 to quit.\nchoice: ";

/**____________________________________________________________________________
*/
int intPrompt(const char *prompt) {
    int n;
    printf("%s",prompt);
    scanf(" %d",&n);
    return n;
}
/**____________________________________________________________________________
*/
int main(void) {

    int hours;
    float gross;
    float net;
    float taxes;
    int choice;

    while((choice=intPrompt(szMainMenu))!=5) {

        if(choice>=1 && choice<=4)
            hours=intPrompt("Enter the number of hours worked this week: ");

        switch (choice) {
        case 1:

            if (hours <= BASEHRS)
                gross = hours * BASEPAY1;
            else
                gross = BASEHRS * BASEPAY1 + (hours - BASEHRS) * BASEPAY1 * OVERTIME;
            if (gross <= AMT1)
                taxes = gross * RATE1;
            else if (gross <= AMT1 + AMT2)
                taxes = AMT1 * RATE1 + (gross - AMT1) * RATE2;
            else
                taxes = AMT1 * RATE1 + AMT2 * RATE2 + (gross - AMT1 - AMT2) * RATE3;
            net = gross - taxes;

            printf("gross: $%.2f \n", gross);
            printf("taxes: $%.2f \n", taxes);
            printf("net: $%.2f \n", net);
            break;
        case 2:

            if (hours <= BASEHRS)
                gross = hours * BASEPAY2;
            else
                gross = BASEHRS * BASEPAY2 + (hours - BASEHRS) * BASEPAY2 * OVERTIME;
            if (gross <= AMT1)
                taxes = gross * RATE1;
            else if (gross <= AMT1 + AMT2)
                taxes = AMT1 * RATE1 + (gross - AMT1) * RATE2;
            else
                taxes = AMT1 * RATE1 + AMT2 * RATE2 + (gross - AMT1 - AMT2) * RATE3;
            net = gross - taxes;

            printf("gross: $%.2f \n", gross);
            printf("taxes: $%.2f \n", taxes);
            printf("net: $%.2f \n", net);
            break;
        case 3:

            if (hours <= BASEHRS)
                gross = hours * BASEPAY3;
            else
                gross = BASEHRS * BASEPAY3 + (hours - BASEHRS) * BASEPAY3 * OVERTIME;
            if (gross <= AMT1)
                taxes = gross * RATE1;
            else if (gross <= AMT1 + AMT2)
                taxes = AMT1 * RATE1 + (gross - AMT1) * RATE2;
            else
                taxes = AMT1 * RATE1 + AMT2 * RATE2 + (gross - AMT1 - AMT2) * RATE3;
            net = gross - taxes;

            printf("gross: $%.2f \n", gross);
            printf("taxes: $%.2f \n", taxes);
            printf("net: $%.2f \n", net);
            break;
        case 4:

            if (hours <= BASEHRS)
                gross = hours * BASEPAY4;
            else
                gross = BASEHRS * BASEPAY4 + (hours - BASEHRS) * BASEPAY4 * OVERTIME;
            if (gross <= AMT1)
                taxes = gross * RATE1;
            else if (gross <= AMT1 + AMT2)
                taxes = AMT1 * RATE1 + (gross - AMT1) * RATE2;
            else
                taxes = AMT1 * RATE1 + AMT2 * RATE2 + (gross - AMT1 - AMT2) * RATE3;
            net = gross - taxes;

            printf("gross: $%.2f \n", gross);
            printf("taxes: $%.2f \n", taxes);
            printf("net: $%.2f \n", net);
            break;

        default:
            _clrscr();
            printf(
                "Invalid choice, please enter the number that corresponds\n"
                "to your rate or press 5 to quit.\n\n"
                "press a key to continue");
            _getch();
        }

        _clrscr();
    }

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```